# Creating empty multidimensional array with different data types in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, struct

I'm trying to figure out how to create a structure with multidimensional array.

I got it working for 1D array:

```swift
struct example1 {

var user: [String] 

}
```

but when I try to create an array with String, String, Int and a Bool it gives me "Expected ']' in array type" error

```swift
struct example2 {

var user: [[String], [String], [Int],[Bool]]

}
```

How to create empty multidimensional array that would work in structure like mine?

Comment: What is the purpose of that data model?

Comment: It's for an exercise where I'm supposed to create a struct that'd hold user data like name, email, age and a true/false bool.

Comment: Then use a `struct` rather than multiple arrays.

Comment: Then you should use another struct for this.

Comment: You're trying to make do with the tools you know (arrays). While I can appreciate that, it's just not the right tool for the job. You need a `User` struct, with properties you want (my guess is probably `firstName: String`, `lastName: String`, `age: Int` and some other boolean). You can then make an array of `User` structs.

Comment: So for each user I'd have to create a new struct? or would there be another way to hold multiple users within the same struct that I'd add using.append later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple arrays are bad practice for several reasons.

Create a struct `User`, each instance holds all information of **one** user

```
struct User {

    let name : String
    let email : String
    let age : Int
    let someBoolean : Bool
}
```

Declare the array

```
var users = [User]()
```

and add an item

```
let newUser = User(name: "Foo", email: "foo@something.com", age: 12, someBoolean: false)
users.append(newUser)
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted to achieve!
Why are multidimensional arrays not recommended?

Comment: Imagine you have to move one user from index 2 to index 6. Multiple arrays will drive you crazy.

Comment: @onesadlittleboy Among other things, Swift's arrays always have elements of a single type, such as `Int`, or `String`. If you want multiple types, then you need to use a more general type like a protocol or a superclass. The most general type is `Any` (which matches values of literally any type, be it `Int`, or `String`, or anything else), and you'll often see `[Any]`, particularly working with unannoted Objective C APIs. The issue is that more general types achieve their generality by specificity less requirements. `Any` is a protocol with literally no requirements. ...

Comment: There's really nothing you can do with a value of type any `Any`. You can pass it around (such as to `print`, whose parameter has type `Any`), but that's about it. Doing anything useful at all with it requires you down cast it to the particular type, such as `Int` or `String` or whatever. For example, you can't do `let x: Any = "Some string"; x.uppercased`, because `uppercased` doesn't exist on `Any`. Using arrays of `Any` just devolves into needing to do casts all over the place, like `(x as! String).uppercased`. Structs solve this by allowing different types to coexist in a single struct.